# How do I show $|\frac{i\overline{z}}{2} - \frac{i}{2}|=|z - 1|?$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was looking over an example from our book concerning limits, and I'm having trouble seeing how this equality holds.

Comment: Looking for a counterexample works: does it work for $z=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{i\overline z}2-\frac i2\,\right|=\left|\frac i2\right|\;|\overline z-1|=\frac12\;|\overline z-1|=\frac12\; |z-1|$$

No, it doesn't look the same.

Comment: was going to do the same!

Comment: So, it's a mistake in the text?

Comment: Gotcha @Aditya ...lol

Comment: Yes @Mark, it seems as it is. Are you sure you weren't asked to find out *what* $\;z\;$ fulfill the equality?

Comment: @Timbuc No, only that $|Z| < 1$

Comment: Well @Mark, if you didn't make some mistake copying the question then yes: it is an error in that book.

Comment: @Timbuc I didn't. And thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try letting $z=a+bi$, and so $\bar{z}=a-bi$.

Comment: Of course I tried that before asking here. This isn't my homework, btw.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  In fact, I think you're right: It looks like those $2$'s in the denominators on the left side make the statement false.